# auDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client can't connect to localhost

Tags: android, android-emulator, localhost, jbpm

I'm trying to connect the server that can be accessed by following url in my android project emulator. which is 5.1 wvga of google 21 API

```
URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/jbpm-console/rest/runtime/org.jbpm:Evaluation:1.0/process/evaluation/start?   map_employee=krisv&map_reason=Need%20a%20raise");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

But I'm getting an error,

> auDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client If I change the address from
>   10.0.2.2 to localhost, get a error
>
> ```
> ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
> ```

Comment: WHich one you like better?

Comment: `...../start?   map_employee=krisv......`. Spaces there? For what?